# How to represent sum/union types in in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to document an existing use of JSON using json-schema.  The system permits the following two possabilities for one of the object attributes.

Either

```
{
    "tracking_number" : 123
}
```

Or

```
{
    "tracking_number" : [ 123, 124, 125 ]
}
```

How can I express this using json schema?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `anyOf` to assert that the property must conform to one or another schema.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "tracking_number": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/tracking_number" },
                { "type": "array", "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/tracking_number" }
            ]
    },
    "definitions": {
        "tracking_number": { "type": "integer" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out that "oneOf" was better for me in this situation.  But you set me on the right path.

Comment: These keywords are described here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html