# How to set variable Request format in Amazon Api Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, gateway

I want to make a Model for request where some part of the request structure may change.

As i don't have uniform structure here. How can i define `json` model for `Amazon Api Gateway`?

**Request:**

Here data inside `items.{index}.data` is changing according to `type_id`. Also we are not sure about which item with perticular `type_id` come at which `{index}`. even the type of `items.{index}.data` may change.

```
  {
    "name":"Jon Doe",
    "items": [
      {
        "type_id":2,
        "data": {
          "km": 10,
          "fuel": 20
        }
      },
      {
        "type_id": 5,
        "data": [
          [
            "id":1,
            "value":2
          ],
          .....
        ]
      },{
        "type_id": 3,
        "data": "data goes here"
      },
      ....
    ]
  }
```

How should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway uses JSON schema for model definitions. You can use a *union datatype* to represent your data object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450405/how-to-represent-sum-union-types-in-in-json-schema) for an example of such a datatype.

Please note that a data model such as this will pose problems for generating SDKs. If you need SDK support for strictly typed languages, you may want to reconsider this data model.